# Python Regex to match every words in sentence until a last word has underscore in it

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to find the regex which can match every word in sentence until a last word has an **underscore** in it.

For example:

```
13wfe + 123dg Text ldf_dfdlj_dfldjf_dfs test 123
```

In this example, I am looking to get only

```
13wfe + 123dg Text
```

I have tried using something along the line of these,

```
^.*?(?=_)
```

but it is returning this

```
13wfe + 123dg Text ldf
```

You can find the [regex](https://regex101.com/r/OfP5eS/1) here. Kindly guide me in this scenario.

Update: using the [regex](https://regex101.com/r/j6iSwd/1) provided by @liginity, I am able to find the substring, but in some cases it is still failing.

Such as in this example:

```
 13wfe + 123dg Tetest_xt ldf_dfdlj_dfldjf_dfs test 123
```

It should be able to find on this much:

```
13wfe + 123dg Tetest_xt
```

But it is finding multiple:

```
13wfe + 123dg and _xt
```

Comment: Do you really need a regex for that?

Comment: @luk2302 yes, please.

Comment: @Freeman no, it's not working. It's capturing almost everything.

Comment: How about `re.search(r"(.*?)(?=\w+_)", "13wfe + 123dg Text ldf_dfdlj_dfldjf_dfs test 123")`?

Comment: @liginity But in some cases it is not working properly. Such as this one: `13wfe + 123dg Tetest_xt ldf_dfdlj_dfldjf_dfs test 123`, it should only ignore the last one

Comment: Do you mean to include `Tetest_xt` in the match in your example? But in the question title the goal is to stop at the first word with `_` in it. Am I mistaking something?

Comment: It seems the question was altered from "...until a word with _..." to the one now. It seems to me that modfying the last suggestion slightly to `r"(.*\b)(?=\w+_)"` should solve the new problem.

Comment: @Flow sorry for the confusion. Yes, I made a mistake while explaining the situation. Sorry again. And, your solution works perfectly.

Comment: @liginity sorry for the confusion. Yes, I made a mistake while explaining the situation. Sorry again.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to match any non whitespace char as a "word" you can use `\S+`

```
^.*\S(?=[^\S\n]+[^\s_]+_)
```

- `^` Start of string
- `.*` Match the whole line
- `\S` Match a non whitespace char
- `(?=` Positive lookahead

  - `[^\S\n]+` Match 1+ whitespace chars without newlines
  - `[^\s_]+_` Match 1+ non whitespace chars without `_` and then match the `_`
- `)` Close the lookahead

**Note** that if the `_` can also be at the beginning of the word, you can use `[^\s_]*_` where `*` repeats zero or more times.

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/C9tpNJ/1).

Matching all until a last word (where a word consists only of word chars `\w`) has an underscore in it (so not at the start or the end of the word) where `(?<!\S)` and `(?!\S)` are left and right hand whitespace boundaries:

```
^.*(?<!\S)\S+(?=[^\S\n]+[^\W_]+_\w+(?!\S))
```

See another [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/PqUpo9/1).