# Python Regex to match every words in sentence until a last word has hyphen in it, not working

Tags: python, regex

I have this [regex](https://regex101.com/r/pAEof4/1) to find the words in a sentence until the last word which has hyphen in it.

This is my input string:

```
 13wfe + 123dg Tetest-xt ldf-dfdlj-dfldjf-dfs test 123
```

And so far using this regex, from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76604458/python-regex-to-match-every-words-in-sentence-until-a-last-word-has-underscore-i), I am getting match like this:

```
 13wfe + 123dg Tetest-xt ldf-dfdlj-
```

But my expected output should be only this:

```
 13wfe + 123dg Tetest-xt
```

And this is the regex `(.*\b)(?=\w+-)` I am using.

I do not want the last word which has hyphen in it. Kindly guide me in this scenario.

Comment: Looks like a boundary issue, use a whitespace `\s` pattern rather than the word boundary `\b`, i.e. `.*(?=\s\w+-)` (see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/Uel8JX/1)).

Comment: If you do not expect empty matches, and you want to trim them automatically, use `.*\w(?=\s+\w+-)`. This will also handle the cases with more than one whitespace before the last hyphenated word. And just in case: if there can be any non-word chars where `\s+` is, replace `\s+` with `\W+`.

Answer (score 1):

Just add a space, separate from the last word `(.*)(?=\s\w+-)` and the word boundary is useless

> [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/rmRijm/2)

Comment: There should be no word boundary here. It will lead to wrong results if there are more than one whitespace before the word with a hyphen. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76605838/python-regex-to-match-every-words-in-sentence-until-a-last-word-has-hyphen-in-it#comment135065094_76605838) is correct, no need of an additional capturing group.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following pattern.
If the text does not contain a hyphenated word, the entire text is captured.

```
(.+?\w+(?:-\w+)+|.+)(?: +.+)?
```

```py
strings = ['abc 123 def 456 ghi 789 jkl',
           'abc 123 def 456 ghi 789-jkl',
           'abc 123 def 456-ghi 789-jkl',
           'abc 123 def-456 ghi-789-jkl',
           'abc-123 def-456 ghi-789-jkl']
pattern = re.compile(r'(.+?\w+(?:-\w+)+|.+)(?: +.+)?')
for string in strings:
    print(pattern.match(string).group(1))
```

Output

```
abc 123 def 456 ghi 789 jkl
abc 123 def 456 ghi 789-jkl
abc 123 def 456-ghi
abc 123 def-456
abc-123
```